# Forcing some random points to be on a circle via optimization

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, circles, computational-geometry

Can an optimization problem be solved so that some finite number of randomly initialized points in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space (where $d \geq 2$) are positioned on a circle, sphere or hypersphere?

Points inside or outside the circle are "pushed" to the circle. Can this be done for a circle with predefined radius or any arbitrary circle? Here are some illustrations:

[image]

I can think of maximizing or minimizing the Euclidean distance of the points and a center within a constraint if $R$ is known, but what if this $R$ is not known or we do not have information about center or we don’t care?

Comment: Line $CM$ joining point $M$ to the center $C$ of the circle intersect this circle in a point $M'$ that looks a good candidate...

Comment: Why not just map each point to the closest point on the circle?

Comment: If you know neither the center nor the radius, then estimate them.

Comment: I was thinking about this in an iterative learning manner. So the points after the first random initialization are learned using a moving average. Mapping can be good. If I know the center and the radius, then how do I write the optimization problem?

Comment: Suppose the center is $\bf c$ and the radius is $r$. Use ${\bf y} := {\bf x - c}$ to center the circle at the origin. Then normalize each of the points. Then scale each by $r$. Finally, add $\bf c$. Done. Why exactly do you need optimization? It's simple normalization. No need to complicate.